# Counting frequency of generic object in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, generic-programming

Im creating a method to count the frequency of a value that is the methods parameter. I have created a binary tree and put values into it, im now trying to count all the values that equals the parameter.
The problem is im getting a infinite loop, can anybody see why:

```
public int counter(T value)
  {
     if (value == null) return 0;
      Node<T> p = root, q = null; // q is the parent of p
      int values = 0;


    while (p != null)                           // checks p
    {
      int cmp = comp.compare(p.value,value);// compares

      if(p.value.equals(value))
      {
          values++;
      }

      if (cmp < 0) { q = p; p = p.left; }      // goes left in the tree
      else if (cmp > 0) { q = p; p = p.rigth; }  goes right in the tree


     if ( p == null) return values;
        }


      return 0; // if no values found in the tree 
  }
```

Constructor:

```
   private Node(T value, Node<T> l, Node<T> r) 
    {
      this.value = value;
      left = l; right = r;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find a matching value you increment the counter but then don't change `p`, so you're stuck on the same node forever after that.

Any solution where the tree can contain more than one instance of a value is going to have to be recursive.  Just draw a tree with, say, 6 instances of a particular value and walk through your code.  You have to look at *both* subtrees at that point, so recursion is the only way to do this easily (or, you could use a parent-pointer stack as well, I suppose, but recursion is so much cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! Im not good at trees or recursive methods, but this is my try, im getting stack overflow so this is again a infinite loop. But I just dont know how to solve this.

```
 public int counter(T value)
  {
     if (value == null) return 0;
      Node<T> p = root, q = null;
      int countervalues = 0;

     if(p.value.equals(value))
      {
          countervalues++;
      }


  if(p.left!=null) p = p.left; counter(value);


  if(p.right!=null) counter(value);



     if(p.left == null && p.left == null)
         return countervalues;



      return 0;
  }
```